# Heroku app writing to wrong database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I created a fork from my production app on Heroku by running this command from their docs:

`heroku fork --from prod --to stage`

After experiencing a bunch of issues, I realized the new staging fork is writing to my production database.

Why would it do this by default, and how do I make it use it's own database?

Edit: What makes this even more odd is that when I run `heroku pg:info --app stage`, it shows `Add-on` points to the correct DB for stage.  So the DB add-on is correct, but it's writing to the other app's DB.

Comment: I have experienced this issue with my apps too.
I had to redeploy the app to get it working normally again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using the pg:promote command to assign the stage DB to the stage app:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE --app sushi
```

I still have no idea what caused the issue in the first place though, as I don't have the DB name hardcoded anywhere.